# 3TB SATA drive takes about 5 minutes to be discovered by BIOS or Windows

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

I have a 3TB internal SATA drive that's taking about 5 minutes to be discovered by the BIOS or in Windows.
I'm not sure what the issue is but I KNOW this is not usual. I have 8 other 3-8 TB SATA drives in this system and none of them take that long (maybe 10-15 seconds) It's the same on my other system I have 8 3-8 TB SATA drives that take about the same. I also have a USB 3.0 drive that mirrors each of them and they take maybe 20-25 seconds to be discovered by windows. In their totality the USB drives take about 2-3 minutes to be discovered by the bios when booting up but a single drive should only take seconds not minutes to be discovered. Spaccy says the SMART for the drive is fine. I also did a scandisk from within windows and Windows reports no issues. Anyone have any experience with something like this happening to them or any experience they'd like to offer.

BTW when I disconnect this drive on bootup my system boots up in about 20-25 seconds (When the USB drives are not connected.) Even with 7 other SATA HD Drives connected. Not including the SSD the OS is on.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had drives do that.

Within months, they completely fail to spin up.

Consider yourself lucky: You have an opportunity to know the problem in advance, so you can immediately back up anything critical, and get a new drive (and then can clone the drive) in a not-panicky-rushed scenario.

I do suppose there may be other causes, such as BIOS incompatibilities.  Using the drive in another system might work fine.  I know my prediction sounds rather doom-and-gloom.  However, ethically I feel obligated to let you know my prediction, because that is what has matched reality for me more than any other reasons.

(This is based on somewhat older info; based on spinning magnetic hard drives, not SSDs.)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. Yeah I kind of figured that. It's actually a backup drive itself so I still have another copy of the data that's on it. This drive actually died already. But I always try them again just to make sure they're dead. In this case I was able to reformat the drive and then back up a full 3TB drive to it and it kept working. Very unusual in my experience for a drive to work again once they've packed it in. But it happens. I'm really quite surprised it hasn't died yet. I was starting to think maybe the drive was really ok since the SMART for the drive says it's fine and MS Checkdisk says it has no problems I thought maybe the reformat fixed whatever ailed the drive. But I think your prediction is far more likely in spite of these supposed drive tools. Tell me are the SMART indicators of ANY use at all. Every drive I've had die reported no issues according to SMART right to the point that they were dead. I've actually looked for a decent tool that would monitor the SMART of my drives (because I've got a lot of them) and email me or let me know somehow when one of them actually develops issues according to SMART. But alas I've never found a tool that could do that. Besides from my experience SMART is nonsense anyway.